# Yii2 select2 database exception number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, jquery-select2

when i use select2 widget in my yii 2 applicaton, it will cause the following error:

```
SQLSTATE [HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE `page`.`id`=6
```

The executed sql does not apply my override in find function of Page model as follow:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['websiteId' => Yii::$app->website->id]);
}
```

Debug stack hint me to beforeInsert() function in ActiveRecord at line 333 & this code:

```
$this->node->refresh();
```

Every thing seems ok, so whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem, It seems to be a bug in framework!
Just find **refresh()** function & change the following line in **vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php** file

```
$query->where($pk);
```

to

```
$query->andWhere($pk);
```